# How can i embed a file, committed on svn, into my html page?

Tags: html, svn, iframe, embed, xls

Is there anyway that I can display an xls file committed on SVN onto my webpage(HTML) in an iframe or something?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you're asking/expecting but here is what is possible:

- You can commit an XLS file to an SVN repo
- Assuming you can make that SVN repo public (or access it from the web server) you should be able to display it on a webpage, but only as a link to the file, which others can download.
- If you want to actually display the contents of the XLS you would have to read the file in code, and display it in a table you create in code
- You could do something like convert the file to a Google Doc, and display that in an iFrame (From memory their API is pretty good so you could likely interface with their API to write some code to upload the file etc)
- You could use other frameworks or similar to load the data into table like structures in HTML e.g http://www.datatables.net/

Comment: I wanted to display the content of the file committed on svn. I did that using google docs iframe, but thats not live. Every time i make changes to the file, I need to republish it for changes to get reflected. Is there anyway that i could edit the file there in the page/iframe itself?

Comment: You can edit the file in the page itself because it's a google doc, but the changes are in google not your svn.